# Джойстик для игры LibGDX

Tags: android-studio, разработка-игр, libgdx

Мне нужно реализовать джойстик для игры. Объясните с чего начать и что для этого использовать(Например: считывать касание пальца по координатам или есть специальная переменная, как у Button?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел способ для реализации: существует `Gdx.input.isTouched(i);` - метод, который возвращает true если палец пользователя касается экрана и false в обратном случае, и i - это id пальца. Дальше через цикл начинаем обработку каждого пальца на экране (максимум можете выбрать сами, но некоторые устройства могут не поддерживать такое количество):

`for (int i = 0; i < fingers; i++)
   if (Gdx.input.isTouched(i))`

И далее получаете координаты каждого пальца через

`Gdx.input.getX(i)` для получения X координаты

`Gdx.input.getY(i)` для получения Y координаты

Единственное - значения могут быть наоборот, т.е. вы нажимаете на точку (200, 400) (экран 360:640), а получаете к примеру (200, 240). Проверяйте это или же посмотрите как пользоваться

`Vector3 toychPos = new Vector3();
touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(i), Gdx.input.getY(i), 0);
camera.unproject(touchPos);`

Answer (score 0):

Делайте как вам удобно, нет правильного или неправильного способа.
Могу предложить вариант с просчетом нажатия на экран в определенной области, и исходя из точки нажатия относительно центра этого "джойстика" уже что-либо делать с миром/персонажем.

Comment: Буду рад, если отправите

Comment: @Dartik увы, но тут не пишут за кого-то код, а помогают с криво работающим готовым

Comment: Я конечно понимаю, но "просчитывать нажатия относительно центра джойстика" не сложная идея, чтобы самому догадаться. Мне нужна помощь в реализации, а не просто комментарии

Comment: @Dartik на это могу только посоветовать учить матчасть... (т.к. реализация в пару строк базовая)